# Adding a checkboxcolumn to DataGridView, WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

**DataGridView settings** 
Enable Adding is false 
Enable Editing is false 
Enable Deleting is false 
Enable Column Reordering is false

All those above settings applied I tried to see a check mark on checkboxcolumn when I click but fail, It does not appear my click actions on checkboxcolumn even I used below code.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try with true for editing and adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make only one column as readonly if datagridview on a whole is set as readonly (i.e. Enable editting to false )

So, firstly you need to set that to

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly =false;
```

Next, you need to set all the columns in your code as readonly.

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvCol1 in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
     dgvCol1.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Lastly, set the required column's readonly property ( in your case the checkbox column )
to false.

```
dataGridView1.Columns("ColumnName").ReadOnly = false;
```

I hope this solution is useful for you.

Comment: till clicking a CheckBoxColumn works fine even one clicking is enough to make whole GridDataView as ReadOnly True. But if not a click on CheckboxColumn then user who temperate data in DataGridView is possible. This looks as an handicap.